# In the Elixir Supervisor and Application tutorial, why does the assert_receive time out?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

In the Elixir Getting Started tutorial, on the page about [Supervisors and Applications](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html), there's a test called "removes bucket on crash". After adding the code on the page (I think I added it, could have missed something), the test fails with a timeout in the assert_receive.

```
test "removes bucket on crash", %{registry: registry} do
    KV.Registry.create(registry, "shopping")
    {:ok, bucket} = KV.Registry.lookup(registry, "shopping")

    # Kill the bucket and wait for the notification
    Process.exit(bucket, :shutdown)
    assert_receive {:exit, "shopping", ^bucket}
    assert KV.Registry.lookup(registry, "shopping") == :error
end
```

Here's the output:

```
$ mix test
....

1) test removes bucket on crash (KV.RegistryTest)
   test/kv/registry_test.exs:49
   No message matching {:exit, "shopping", ^bucket} after 100ms. Process mailbox:
   {:create, "shopping", #PID<0.137.0>}
   stacktrace:
     test/kv/registry_test.exs:55
```

The help for Process.exit says the message would be {:EXIT, from, reason} if the process trapped exits.

What's a good strategy for tracking down bugs like this?

Comment: The code in my repo is here: https://github.com/ijt/kv/tree/stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your implementation is [in this line](https://github.com/ijt/kv/blob/stackoverflow/lib/kv/registry.ex#L65)
You wait for the `:DOWN` message with an exit reason `:normal`. If the bucket process terminates with any other reason, you won't match this message, and it won't be propagated to the `GenEvent`.

Changing `:normal` to `_` (to match any reason for the process exit) fixed the test.

The way I came to it is that, after understanding the code and seeing no obvious mistakes, I added some temp. `IO.inspect` in a few places. I immediately noticed that the registry process doesn't handle the `:DOWN` message. Seeing that the monitor is properly set-up, I suspected that there has to be something wrong with how the message is pattern-matched. Staring at that line for few seconds gave me the answer :-)

Comment: That did it. Turns out the change to that line of code was on the previous page of the tutorial (http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genevent.html).